# RAFT consensus protocol - Should entries be durable before commiting

Tags: consensus, raft

I have the following query about implementation RAFT:

Consider the following scenario\implementation:

1. RAFT leader receives a command entry, it appends the entry to an
   in-memory array It then sends the entries to followers (with the
   heartbeat)
2. The followers receive the entry and append it to their
   in-memory array and then send a response that it has received the
   entry
3. The leader then commits the entry by writing it to a durable
   store (file) The leader sends the latest commit index in the
   heartbeat
4. The followers then commit the entries based on leader's
   commit index by storing the entry to their durable store (file)

One of the implementations of RAFT (link: https://github.com/peterbourgon/raft/) seems to implement it this way.  I wanted to confirm if this fine.

Is it OK  if entries are maintained "in memory" by the leader and the followers until it is committed? In what circumstances might this scenario fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to the question by posting to raft-dev google group. I have added the answer for reference.

Please reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/raft-dev/_lav2NeiypQ/1QbUB52fkggJ

Quoting Diego's answer:

> For safety even in the face of correlated power outages, a majority of
>   servers needs to have persisted the log entry before its effects are 
>   externalized. Any less than a majority and those servers could 
>   permanently fail, resulting in data loss/corruption

Quoting from [Ben Johnson's](https://github.com/benbjohnson) answer to my email regarding the same:

> No, a server has to flush entries to disk before being considered part
>   of the quorum.
>
> For example, let's say you have a cluster of nodes called A, B, & C
>   where A is the leader.
>
> 1. Node A replicates an entry to Node B.
> 2. Node B stores entry in memory and responds to Node A.
> 3. Node A now has a quorum and commits the entry.
> 4. Node A then gets partitioned away from Node B & C.
> 5. Node B then dies and loses the in-memory copy of the entry.
> 6. Node B comes back up.
> 7. When Node B & C then go to elect a leader, the "committed" entry will not be in their log.
> 8. When Node A rejoins the cluster, it will have an inconsistent log. The entry will have been committed and applied to the state machine so
>      it can't be rolled back.
>
> Ben

Comment: I believe in step 6 node B need to read a quorum of machine for the latest commited index before joining. But this is not possible since node A is still partitioned. 

So what should happen is that node B should stay in stand-by mode until Node A join, then Node B will read latest commited index from node A.

Another option is if in step 4 on of B or C become leader it will need 2 votes and thus the latest commited entry will be stored on both node (B & C)

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the accepted answer.

1. A disk isn't mystically durable. Assuming the disk is local to the server it can permanently fail. So clearly writing to disk doesn't save you from that. Replication *is* durability provided that the replicas live in different failure domains which if you are serious about durability they will be. Of course there are many hazards to a process that disks don't suffer from (linux oom killed, oom in general, power etc), but a dedicated process on a dedicated machine can do pretty well. Especially if the log store is say ramfs, so process restart isn't an issue.
2. If log storage is lost then host identity should be lost as well. A,B,C identify logs. New log, new id. B "rejoining" after (potential) loss of storage is simply a buggy implementation. The new process can't claim the identity of B because it can't be sure that it has all the information that B had. Just like in the case of always flushing to disk if we replaced the disk of the machine hosting B we couldn't just restart the process with it configured to have B's identity. That would be nonsense. It should restart as D in both cases then ask to join the cluster. At which point the problem of losing committed writes disappears in a puff of smoke.

Answer (score 0):

I think entries should be durable before commiting.

Let's take the Figure 8(e) of the Raft extended paper as an example. If entries are durable when committed, then:

1. S1 replicates 4 to S2 and S3 then commit 2 and 4.
2. All servers crash. Because S2 and S3 don't know S1 has commited 2 and 4, they won't commit 2 and 4. Therefore S1 has commited 1,2,4, S2, S3, S4, S5 has commited 1.
3. All servers restart except S1.
4. Because only commited entries are durable, S2, S3, S4, S5 have the same single entry: 1.
5. S2 is elected as the leader.
6. S2 replicates a new entry to all other servers except the crashed S1.
7. S1 restarts. Because S2's entries are newer than S1, so S1's 2 and 4 are replaced by the previous new entry.

As a result, the commited entries 2 and 4 are lost. So I think the un-commited entries should be also durable.

Comment: Not really. In the case of a memory only implementation process crashes are permanent failures requiring new identities to join the cluster. If you kill every server at the same time then you've breached the N = 2f - 1 condition and your cluster is toast. Processes maintaining their identities but not their logs _is buggy_ be it single local disk, raid array, in process memory, tmpfs, SAN array or whatever.